# Minimum number of independent trials needed to detect a bias

Tags: statistical-test

Suppose, I suspect that the probability of occurrence of a particular bit as $0$ is $.558$. Since, it is not $.5$, so this is *possibly* a bias. Now, my question is:

> What is the minimum number of independent trials I need to confirm my result?

I mean, observing this scenario for, say 100 times, must not be convincing. There should be a theoretical result regarding this. It would be very helpful if someone links such papers while answering.

What I am looking for is: Suppose I suspect a possible bias of $0.5 \pm x$, $x \in (0, .5]$. Then, at least, say $2^{1/x}$ trials are need to confirm my suspicion.

Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417981/calculate-the-number-of-trials-needed-to-achieve-certain-number-of-successes-at

Comment: Is this just confidence intervals for a binomial distribution?

Comment: @bmm6o I don't think so! *Or, probably I am misunderstanding.* Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @owlstead Sorry for late response. But I am not getting what exactly bmm6o and you are talking about.

Comment: @ moderators: Could you migrate the question to math.stackexchange ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "@moderators", you should flag your question to gain attention.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about cryptography, and this question is too old to be migrated. Sorry, tried to migrate but the system won't let me.

Answer (score 4):

I searched the web, and finally *(I think)* I got:

In page 47, 48 of this [thesis](http://souravsengupta.com/pub/phd_thesis_2013.pdf), it is mentioned that -

> To detect a bias of $p(1+q)$ (where $p$ is the probability for an Uniform Random event), we need roughly $\dfrac{1}{pq^2}$ samples.

Comment: That seems to be the correct order of magnitude. Statisticians have more precise evaluations, taking into account the confidence level that we want in the conclusions. We are talking about a [Chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_test) with one degree of freedom. There are also methods to decide dynamically if we can stop the test or continue, for given confidence levels or reaching the wrong conclusions.

Comment: There's good stuff @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair.